# Fullpage.js Jquery code not making the HTML page work as intended

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap-4

I have been trying to follow this tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1iN19bysgxs) and around the 9:08 mark, he adds javascript and then shows that fullpage.js works, but mine does not after I refresh the page after putting in the new code. Am I doing something wrong here?

Thanks.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/fullpage.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section section1">
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Section 1</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam vulputate metus ornare vestibulum vehicula. Mauris nec eros urna. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Curabitur a odio sagittis, vehicula libero porta, auctor odio. Praesent a ultrices neque. Aliquam at tellus lectus. Sed tempus cursus justo sed tincidunt. Aenean quis bibendum velit, et auctor massa. Praesent tincidunt eu quam sed semper. Donec eu quam dapibus, suscipit odio nec, consectetur lectus. Maecenas scelerisque nec velit eu tincidunt. </p>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="section section2">
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Section 2</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam vulputate metus ornare vestibulum vehicula. Mauris nec eros urna. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Curabitur a odio sagittis, vehicula libero porta, auctor odio. Praesent a ultrices neque. Aliquam at tellus lectus. Sed tempus cursus justo sed tincidunt. Aenean quis bibendum velit, et auctor massa. Praesent tincidunt eu quam sed semper. Donec eu quam dapibus, suscipit odio nec, consectetur lectus. Maecenas scelerisque nec velit eu tincidunt. </p>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="section section3">
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Section 3</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam vulputate metus ornare vestibulum vehicula. Mauris nec eros urna. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Curabitur a odio sagittis, vehicula libero porta, auctor odio. Praesent a ultrices neque. Aliquam at tellus lectus. Sed tempus cursus justo sed tincidunt. Aenean quis bibendum velit, et auctor massa. Praesent tincidunt eu quam sed semper. Donec eu quam dapibus, suscipit odio nec, consectetur lectus. Maecenas scelerisque nec velit eu tincidunt. </p>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="section section4">
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Section 4</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam vulputate metus ornare vestibulum vehicula. Mauris nec eros urna. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Curabitur a odio sagittis, vehicula libero porta, auctor odio. Praesent a ultrices neque. Aliquam at tellus lectus. Sed tempus cursus justo sed tincidunt. Aenean quis bibendum velit, et auctor massa. Praesent tincidunt eu quam sed semper. Donec eu quam dapibus, suscipit odio nec, consectetur lectus. Maecenas scelerisque nec velit eu tincidunt. </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/fullpage.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#fullpage').fullpage({
        //options here
        autoScrolling:true,
        scrollHorizontally: true,
        navigation: true
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working demo from your code. I think you have an issue with the [fullpage.js](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/fullPage.js) library file. In the latest version(3 & up) of fullpage.js, it has changed its license to GPLv3 and it requires a `licenseKey` option. [Read more here](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#options.)

So, check your console & if you found such warnings please get a `licensekey` or downgrade your library version.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#fullpage').fullpage({
        //options here
        autoScrolling:true,
        scrollHorizontally: true,
        navigation: true
    });
});

/**
 * EXTRA JS CODE
 * Only for element background-color
 */
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.section').each(function () {
        var hue = 'rgb(' + (Math.floor((256-199)*Math.random()) + 200) + ',' + (Math.floor((256-199)*Math.random()) + 200) + ',' + (Math.floor((256-199)*Math.random()) + 200) + ')';
        $(this).css("background-color", hue);
    });
});
```

```css
#fp-nav ul li a span {
  background-color: orangered !important;
}
#fp-nav ul li a.active span {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/2.9.7/jquery.fullpage.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section section1">
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Section 1</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam vulputate metus ornare vestibulum vehicula. Mauris nec eros urna. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Curabitur a odio sagittis, vehicula libero porta, auctor odio. Praesent a ultrices neque. Aliquam at tellus lectus. Sed tempus cursus justo sed tincidunt. Aenean quis bibendum velit, et auctor massa. Praesent tincidunt eu quam sed semper. Donec eu quam dapibus, suscipit odio nec, consectetur lectus. Maecenas scelerisque nec velit eu tincidunt. </p>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="section section2">
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Section 2</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam vulputate metus ornare vestibulum vehicula. Mauris nec eros urna. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Curabitur a odio sagittis, vehicula libero porta, auctor odio. Praesent a ultrices neque. Aliquam at tellus lectus. Sed tempus cursus justo sed tincidunt. Aenean quis bibendum velit, et auctor massa. Praesent tincidunt eu quam sed semper. Donec eu quam dapibus, suscipit odio nec, consectetur lectus. Maecenas scelerisque nec velit eu tincidunt. </p>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="section section3">
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Section 3</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam vulputate metus ornare vestibulum vehicula. Mauris nec eros urna. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Curabitur a odio sagittis, vehicula libero porta, auctor odio. Praesent a ultrices neque. Aliquam at tellus lectus. Sed tempus cursus justo sed tincidunt. Aenean quis bibendum velit, et auctor massa. Praesent tincidunt eu quam sed semper. Donec eu quam dapibus, suscipit odio nec, consectetur lectus. Maecenas scelerisque nec velit eu tincidunt. </p>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="section section4">
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Section 4</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam vulputate metus ornare vestibulum vehicula. Mauris nec eros urna. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Curabitur a odio sagittis, vehicula libero porta, auctor odio. Praesent a ultrices neque. Aliquam at tellus lectus. Sed tempus cursus justo sed tincidunt. Aenean quis bibendum velit, et auctor massa. Praesent tincidunt eu quam sed semper. Donec eu quam dapibus, suscipit odio nec, consectetur lectus. Maecenas scelerisque nec velit eu tincidunt. </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.js"></script>
<!--- Default Library - v2.9.7
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/2.9.7/jquery.fullpage.min.js"></script>
-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/2.9.7/jquery.fullpage.extensions.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I downloaded the 2.9.7 version of fullpage.js and the website works flawlessly.